# NetBeans platform icons

Tags: image, netbeans, icons, location

Does anyone know the file or directory where NetBeans icons are stored? Ideally I would like to reuse some of those icons for my application that is based on the NetBeans platform.
Regards,
Kevin

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid the icons are scattered around the various jars that are used by the application. You could probably use an application like SnagIt in order to grab them from the GUI and Inkscape to process them.

Comment: You could also clone the Mecurial repository to get the source code, which would also contain any resources like icons. Be prepared for a rather large clone, though! It will take a while, and a good-sized chunk of disk space to do a clone of the whole repository (~3 GB, 229000+ files in 65000+ folders when I last cloned it in August). If you know kind of what you are looking for and where it might be you might be able to clone just a part of the repo, or even get it directly from the repository browser online.